# set -f inside function

Tags: bash, find, function, set

I have a directory with files `file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c`. The command `find`  outputs:

```
$find -name "*.c"
./file1.c
./file2.c
./file3.c
```

Then I would like to use `find`  without the quotes around `.*c`. For this I use `set -f`:

```
 $echo $-            # check current options
 himBHs
 $set -f
 $echo $-            # check that f option is set
 fhimBHs
 $find -name *.c
 ./file1.c
 ./file2.c
 ./file3.c
 $set +f             # unset f option
```

I tried the same commands inside a function in `.bashrc`:

```
find() {
    set -f
    eval command find $@
    set +f
}
```

but testing it gave the error:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc && find -name *c
find: paths must precede expression: file1.c
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression
```

What is the cause for this error in the function? `find` version: GNU 4.6.0

Comment: Remove `eval`, and use `"$(command -v find)" "$@"`

Comment: I followed your suggestion but the function does not output any text and I have to stop with `Ctrl+C`

Comment: ah right, `command -v find` still report your `find` function, maybe better to rename the function to something else other than `find`. In any case, I don't think it's a good solution, because `*.c` still be evaluated before passing to your function, so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say, but you must be calling the function like this:

```
find -name *.c
```

But globbing hasn't been turned off yet, so the shell expands the `*.c` before the call.  So the `find` command sees '-name' followed by three arguments, thus the error message.

You could use a backslash instead of quotes.

```
find -name \*.c
```

Comment: This worked but i ended up doing: `alias find='set -f; find'` and `preexec() { 'set +f'; }`, where preexec()  comes from:  https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec

Comment: ... which also means that the function itself becomes useless (not needed).

Answer (score 1):

Your function disables filename globbing, but you call it with a glob that the shell expands (filename globbing is *not* turned off in the shell that you call it from).

In other words, the glob in your command

```
find -name *c
```

is expanded before your `find` function is called.  This results in a call to `find` inside the function that the utility can't understand.

You could solve that by calling your function with a quoted argument:

```
find -name "*c"
```

but notice how now the function is totally useless as it just replicates the command that you've already typed in.

In *addition* to being useless, it's also wrong. Since `$@` is unquoted in your code, it will split the arguments on whitespaces (by default).  This means that you *can't* use e.g.

```
find -name "* *"
```

to find names with spaces in them.

Also note that due to the `eval`, the shell would perform expansions on the contents of `$@`.  This means that

```
find -name '$(echo hello)'
```

would not find files called `$(echo hello)` but `hello`.

Another thing is that if the calling shell *already* uses `set -f`, then this will be disabled by the function.

---

Let's create a useful function instead.  A function that looks for a *number of* filename patterns, for example:

```
myfind "*.c" "*.txt" "* *"
```

We'd like the above command to return the pathnames that end with `.c` or `.txt` or that contain spaces.

Here's the function:

```
myfind () {
    # Replace each positional parameter "$pattern"
    # with -o -name "$pattern"
    for pattern do
        set -- "$@" -o -name "$pattern"
        shift
    done
    shift  # shift off the initial "-o"

    find . "$@"
}
```

Given the above call of the function, it will end up executing

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '* *'
```

If you are more comfortable using `bash` arrays for lists, and don't mind a bit more typing:

```
myfind () {
    local -a args

    # Build the argument list for find by adding
    # -o -name "$pattern"
    # for each positional parameter 
    for pattern do
        args+=( -o -name "$pattern" )
    done
    args=( "${args[@]:1}" )  # remove the initial "-o"

    find . "${args[@]}"
}
```