# Find: Substitute expression with a variable

Tags: find, quoting, variable, gnu, variable-substitution

```bsh
$ find -name "Bik*"
./Biking
./Biking/Unsync/Biking.md.~6~
./Biking/Rendered/Biking.gen.html
./Biking/Biking.md
```

Now when I substitute expression with a variable as follows:

```bsh
$ a='-name "Bik*"'

$ find $a
```

I get no output. Why is it so? And what should be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Unless you are using `zsh` as your interactive shell...) The issue is that the double quotes will be taken as part of the pattern.  The command that you are actually running would be the equivalent of

```
find . -name '"Bik*"'
```

You get this because the shell would perform word-splitting on the unquoted `$a`, splitting the string tho the two words `-name` and `"Bik*"`.  The words then undergo filename generation ("globbing"), which means that `"Bik*"` would be expanded to all the filenames matching that particular pattern in the current directory (including the double quotes).  It's unlikely that you have any such filenames, so the pattern remains unexpanded, and the quotes remain.

If you had used `a='-name Bik*'`, it would have *worked*, but only if you have nothing matching `Bik*` in the current directory.

If, in `bash`, you had used `shopt -s nullglob`, both attempts would have resulted in an error from `find` as `-name` would not have been given a pattern (the shell would have removed the unmatched patterns).

(In the `zsh` shell, you would get an error from `find` as it does not know what option `-name "Bie*"`, i.e. the *whole string*, is; this is because the `zsh` shell does not perform these split-and-glob operations on unquoted expansions by default.)

Instead, if you are using a shell that has arrays, use

```
a=( -name 'Bik*' )
find . "${a[@]}"
```

This would properly quote each individual word when used with `find` in the way shown here.

Or, you could have used

```
a='Bik*'
find . -name "$a"
```

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)

Also *the second half* of [my solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506622/116858) to [set -f inside function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500085)